# How can I copy only a specific part of an html element through python?

Tags: python

I have to pull a randomly generated ID on a website and copy only the binary number (first 8 digits) out of it to a separate text box.

Here is an example of a generated ID: 73513787 - (0x0461BB3B)
I only need the "73513787".

My current code (to copy and paste everything at once) is:

```
content2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 input-group col-form-label']").text
folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-id='projEditFormInptCustomerReference']")
folder.send_keys(content2)
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The easy way would be deleting the digits via backspace but I wanna do it right straight away... .

Comment: If I understood correctly the content2 is `73513787 - (0x0461BB3B)` and if you only need the `73513787` you can use `.split("-")[0]` after the `.text`.

Comment: Another related question to this. What would I do if I needed the second part of the split? In this case the "(0x0461BB3B)"

Comment: then you use `.split("-")[1]`

Comment: In order to copy the second half ( the "(0x0461BB3B)") change the [0] to a [1]

Comment: What is the role of Selenium in splitting the text? Why tagging Selenium?

Comment: Oh yes, basically the `split("-")` divides the string `73513787 - (0x0461BB3B)` with `-` and bcs there is only one `-` it divides the string into 2 pieces (list of 2 items). If you need the first item you go with [0] and if you need the 2nd tiem you do [1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Leemosh I now have an easy solution to it

Code is now as following:

```
content2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 input-group col-form-label']").text.split("-")[0]
folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-id='projEditFormInptCustomerReference']")
folder.send_keys(content2)
```

The output is 73513787 due to the split.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the split function based on character '-' this will return string array

Try the below example

```
    txt = "73513787 - (0x0461BB3B)"
    x = txt.split('-')
    print(x) // prints ['73513787 ', ' (0x0461BB3B)']    
    print(x[0]) // prints 73513787
```